# JavaScript creating a div dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom, styling

I was trying to create function to create a `div` and style it, here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/NGnEd/5/.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dom = {

    // Build the main button
    buildButton: function(){

        // Create new DOM element - div
        var button = document.createElement('div');

        // Set element attribute
        button.setAttribute('id', 'newElement');

        // Style the element
        button.style.width = "100px";
        button.style.height = "100px";

        // Add content
        button.innerHTML = 'new Element';

        // Print element
        document.body.innerHTML += button;
    }
}
</script>

<div onclick="dom.buildButton();">
   The first div
</div>
```

It is supposed to create element, style it, add content and print it. But it's not working, I don't know the reason.

Any help?

Comment: It "does not work" because you didn't set up the fiddle correctly. The code is put into the `load` event handler, so `dom` is not globally accessible. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/NGnEd/6/ Of course this is still not what you are looking for, but I will let you figure out the rest ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add an HTML element to a string. Instead of

```
document.body.innerHTML += button;
```

Try

```
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Also, as noted by @Felix Kling, you set up the JSFiddle incorrectly, so `onclick="dom.buildButton"` does not work. Working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pnHRp/1/

Comment: Of course it allows global variables... change `onLoad` to `no wrap (head)`.

Comment: Yup, fixed that when I saw your comment.